# Checking the stability analysis of a buck converter using SIMPLIS where to keep POP Trigger

Tags: power-supply, power-electronics, switch-mode-power-supply, simulation, buck

I need to check the stability of below buck converter circuit (12 V in, 5 V out,3A, FSW=500 kHz) using SIMPLIS.

[image]

For this I need to perform an AC analysis. During the AC analysis, I need to keep POP trigger block.

I checked in many places in internet for 'Where to keep this POP trigger block' in the buck converter circuit and how to configure it.

I tried all the methods I found, but my simulation is not working. I am getting the below errors.

**The periodic operating point (POP) analysis has failed to converge.  AC analysis will not be performed.**

**Reaching a time duration equal to
`2.00000e-06' without registering the
triggering condition that defines
the start of a period.  Check your
circuit and/or initial conditions.**

Can someone help me how to configure this block and perform the stability analysis?